# CVS file parser on UNIX command line with sed(1), can it be done?

Tags: shell, csv, parsing, unix, sed

On the UNIX command line we can do simple record-oriented file work using simple field delimiters (or field separators). Common delimiters are space, tab, or vertical bar, but any character can be the delimiter. The commands `sort`, `join`, `cut`, etc. all take the field delimiter as an option -t or -d, and the shell (bourne or bourne again) accepts the IFS environment variable for the `read -a` command to parse a line into an array or the `set --` command to parse a line into the special command line argument variables `$0`, `$1`, ....

The simple field separator approach is easy and the only thing to take care of is that the separator character does not occur in the data itself. Ideally not at all. This can work for specific data sets, but it cannot work in general. This is why on the UNIX shell, and C language (and from there C++, Java) the backslash escape sequences are sometimes used to mark such separators as part of the data (typical `\_` when you have a file name with spaces for example. But that isn't n any way supported by the record and field oriented commands such as sort, cut, and join.

Now, often we get to download a "comma separated values" (CSV) file, which is a format apparently emanating from the Windows world. In it the comma is uses as the separator (a bad choice normally because comma is very likely to be found in the actual data values), and instead of escape sequence, the double quote is used around a data field if it might contain commas (or even spaces). Then inside such a quoted value, if the quote is part of the value, it is "escaped" by doubling it `""`.

Now I am looking for the easiest way to transform a CSV file to a simple delimited file. Any delimiter character can be chosen that doesn't occur in the data.

The difficulty is that the CSV quotation rules require a very simple stateful parser. You are either inside or outside a quoted value. If inside, you need to read the repeated quote `""` as a quote.

I could not find the best answer here and on general internet search I found some things but they were incorrect or used too much tools.

Let's turn this into a contest. The most simple and elegant one-liner that runs on a bourne shell or bash with sed alone (and possibly grep and tr) wins the accepted answer. AWK is permitted if the result is more elegant and if it does not depend on one special version of AWK. Perl is not permitted nor a C program.

I will try my own answer of course.

**UPDATE:** People who don't even bother with sed and move right to awk are having the advantage obviously. If someone can do it elegantly in sed they would be the winner. My own attempt in sed is not elegant.

I have discovered that CSV files may contain line breaks inside quoted fields. That needs to be considered. Since we are trying to create a simple record & field format for UNIX shell processing these embedded line breaks should be converted to \n.

PS: people have asked: why a "one-liner". It doesn't have to be strictly a one liner, the point it that you are able to create that on the command line. Why not Perl? Because most UNIX systems come with the shell and sed and awk, but Perl needs to be installed (and there are all these different versions), same or worse for Python. Before I'd go with Perl or Python I would just write it in C. And no we don't want just any language, it should run on a bare bones UNIX setup without installing a bunch of stuff.

Comment: CSV is an informal, ie. not standardised format. For example, it might be that quotes are escaped thus: `"value \"quoted\""`. Another example: Some parsers might require empty values to be empty between commas (`value,,value`), but others omit them completely (`value,value`).  Your question format _might_ be better suited for CodeGolf, where they often do such contests.

Comment: How is this different from the many other "parse csv with sed" questions already on stackoverflow? How do you propose to choose a delimiter if the CSV file already contains every possible character?

Comment: @rath CSV may be informal but many public data releases come in CSV files. I have never seen backslash escapes in them., And omitting empty fields is obviously broken. I agree there are many broken CSV file approaches around (hence my question) but there is a way to discern good from bad, and we don't have to worry about bad, broken CSV files or parsers. The "gold standard" if you will is "can you open it in Excel"?

Comment: @jhnc I have searched here before. If you have one "parse csv with sed" here on stackoverflow, you are welcome to point to it. I could not find any. Mark this question as duplicate if you want.

Comment: To make it fair, and put all the `awk`-ers on the same baseline: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: @GuntherSchadow consider publishing the benchmark text file that need to be processed

Comment: Why a one-liner? Why not Perl? What about Python? I'm afraid this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow (though it seems pretty much perfect for our sibling site [codegolf.se], though expect replies in languages you have ever heard of).

Answer (score 1):

My (first?) approach is according to the following outline:

1. Determine the best field separator (delimiter) character;
2. replace the (few) occurrences of the chosen delimiter with some (sequence of) other character(s) *A* that doesn't exist anywhere in the data;
3. replace any nested line breaks inside the quotes with `\n`;
4. replace the repeated quote `""` with some (sequence of) other character(s) *B* that doesn't exist anywhere in the data;
5. replace the comma nested inside a quoted field with some (sequence of) other character(s) *C* that doesn't exist anywhere in the data;
6. remove the quotes around the quoted fields (i.e., remove all remaining quotes, as there shouldn't be any left);
7. replace the remaining commas with the chosen delimiter;
8. replace the replacement (sequence of) character(s) *B* for the repeated double quote with the single double quote
9. replace the replacement (sequence of) character(s) *C* for the comma inside a quoted value with the comma.

That is it. The steps 2, 3, and 4 are steps that depend on determining character sequences that do not appear anywhere in the file. That could be `~~`, `^^`, or `$$` or anything. So this is determined with a series of tests. For example:

```
fgrep '|' data.csv
```

and finding only a small number of hits, I now replace | with `$$` because I determine that `$$` does not occur at all:

```
fgrep '$$' data.csv
```

In the same way I determine the replacement for the repeated double quote `""`, say with `^^` and the comma nested inside the quotes I would replace with `##`.

Now I have the data that I need. And with that, the plan above is almost done with:

```
sed <data.csv \
 -e 's/|/$$/g' \
 -e ???????????????? \
 -e 's/""/^^/g' \
 -e 's/???????/???????/g' \
 -e 's/"//g' \
 -e 's/,/|/g' \
 -e 's/^^/"/g' \
 -e 's/##/,/g'
```

You can see each of the numbered steps 2 to 9 in one line each of this sed command. So it's all very clear. Except steps 3 and 5 with the ````` ????????````, the hardest of them all, to replace line breaks and commas nested inside the quotes with the chosen replacement `````\n`and`$$``` respectively.

How would I do that? I need a regex (that sed can actually do), which replaces a comma  inside a quoted string with something else, and without getting the quotes confused.

If all we wanted to do is completely remove the quoted strings we could say

```
 -e 's/,"[^"]*",/,REMOVED,/g' \
```

Instead I do:

```
 -e 's/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g'
```

this would replace it once. I can now repeat that same sed command step many times to catch cases with more than one nested comma:

```
 -e 's/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g'
     -e 's/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g'
     -e 's/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g'
     -e 's/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g'
     ...
```

The problem is I don't know how often I have to replace this. But we can use a more advanced feature of sed: define a label and then jump back to the label when a replacement was made:

```
:c
s/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g
tc
```

defines a label "a" and when the replacement was made, then jump to the label. Or in short on one line:

```
:c;s/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g;tc
```

Finally the joining of the lines separated by newline inside quotes is done with a similar trick:

```
-e ':n;$!N;s/,"\([^"]*\)\n/,"\1\\n/g;tn'
```

the only additional trick here is the `$!N` which is `$` last line, `$!` all but the last line, and `N` is append next line to pattern space so that the regex can search for the line break \n and replace it with the literal `\n`.

```
LANG=C sed <data.csv \
 -e 's/|/$$/g' \
 -e ':n;$!N;s/,"\([^"]*\)\n/,"\1\\n/g;tn' \
 -e 's/""/^^/g' \
 -e ':c;s/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)"/,"\1##\2",/g;tc' \
 -e 's/"//g' \
 -e 's/,/|/g' \
 -e 's/\^\^/"/g' \
 -e 's/##/,/g'
```

So this is now quite a concise approach compared to what I had in the first revision of this answer (see the previous versions for how much better it is now).

PS There may still be errors. Especially I do not currently allow my quoted values to appear as the first field, right now the opening quote `"` is only recognized after a comma.

Comment: save yourself a lot of typing and put all of your sed code, i.e. `s/,"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)",/,"\1##\2",/g` one after each other in a plain text file and then call it like `sed -f myfixer.sed input > output`.  (no need for `-e` or single-quotes or continuation chars). Good luck.

Comment: I noticed that I don't consider that CSV files can have line breaks in the quotes, and this throws my algorithm off. I would need to also replace line breaks inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the vanilla awk CSV tokenizer: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Small modification to replace double quotes inside quoted string with single quotes.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS = "|"
    Q = "\""
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        v = $i
        if ( $i ~ Q ) v = gensub(Q Q, Q, "g", substr(v, 2, length(v)-2))
        printf "%s%s", v, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
```

I'm still working to compact this into one liner ... It's going to be a long line :-).

```
???
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work right when there is a sequence of commas signifying empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, doing character by character processing, keeping states (z-inside quoted string). Needless to say, it assumed input follow rules above.

Not sure if this will qualify as one-liner. ~200 characters.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        Q="\""
        FS=","
        OFS="|"
}

{
        n=split($0,a,"")
        r=""
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++ ) {
                c=a[i]
                if (c==Q) if(a[i+1]==Q) i++ ; else { z=!z ; c="" } ; if (!z&&c==FS) { c=OFS }
                r = r c
        }
        print r
}
```

Comment: This is the best one so far as it seems to be working even with the additional discovery that CSV files can contain line breaks inside the quoted fields. Meaning, it works better than mine in that case. But all of us need to consider that and replace multi-line values with some escape sequence for the newline, for which I would use ```\n```

Comment: @GuntherSchadow  Removed reset of quote stat on new line. This will allow multi-lien constant. Code was working for "foo\nbar\nzoo", but not for "foo\bar,zoo".